# Windbg for memory analysis using mimikatz ERROR

Tags: memory, windbg

I'm using windbg version 6.12 and using mimilib.dll for debugging memory. All works fine until I get following output on UI

```
0:000> !mimikatz

DPAPI Backup keys
=================

Current prefered key:       

Compatibility prefered key: 

SekurLSA
========
[ERROR] [CRYPTO] Acquire keys
```

note: the memory dmp is of `lsass`

Is this anything to do with symbol or respective dll /system32? Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

From the [cross-site duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31042288/windbg-for-memory-analysis-using-mimikatz-error-crypto-acquire-keys) of the same user:

> I was using WinDbg x86 where x64 was required.